# Control error: Invalid JSON response. In dataTables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am working with dataTables to represent my data, and also adds a select field in which, through a query, I load the dataTable again according to the city chosen in my select field, the problem is when I do not have any records of the selected city , And the dataTables sends me the error: Invalid JSON response, how can I control this?

I leave my script and part of my html

```html
//My field select
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <select class="form-control" name="city">
    <option>Filter by city...</option>
      <?php
       foreach ($arrayCity as $id => $name)
        echo '<option  value="',$id,'">'.$name.'</option>';
      ?> 
 </select>
</div>

//My table where I uploaded the data
<table class="table " id="table" width="100%">
 <thead class="thead-inverse">
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>        
   <th>name</th>
   <th>email</th>
   <th>city</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var getUser;
    //Start datatable when loading document.
    getUser = $("#table").DataTable({
        'ajax': baseurl+'User/getUser',
        'orders': [],
        responsive: true
    }); 

    //Function that destroys the dataTable event.
    function destroy_data_table(){
      getUser = $("#table").dataTable();
      if (getUser != undefined){
        getUser.fnDestroy();
      }
    }

    //Select event change to call function
    $('select[name=city]').change(function(){
      destroy_data_table();
      var id = $('select[name=city]').val();
      filterCity(id);
    });


    //Function that reloads the datatable and filters the search by city.
    function filterCity(id){
      getUser = $("#table").DataTable({
       'ajax': baseurl+'City/getCity/'+id,
       'orders': [],
       responsive: true
      }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: You have to check the content returned by `baseurl+'User/getUser'` and `baseurl+'City/getCity/'+id` if they return valid json or not. You can use the network tab of the developer tools to check the requested urls.

Comment: It might be helpful if you show us the code in `baseurl+'User/getUser'`

Comment: Returns the data in json, when there is a user registration of the selected city, everything works fine. But if there is no user from that city, it does not return data to me, my question is how to control that?

Comment: @max there are lot of example highlighting this issue if you bother to google it.